# Python is not existing when ran from System Scheduler

Tags: python, system, scheduler

I have made a batch script which runs a Python application. This batch script is triggered by a program called System Scheduler, but when the program runs the batch script, it says that Python is not exisiting.

When I run my batch script manually, I get no error.

Can anyone explain this or come up with a solution?

Comment: What operating system?  (Please edit the question and add the appropriate tag.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the $PATH is not set properly when called from scheduler. Try changing the command called from

```
python yourscript.py
```

to

```
/usr/bin/python yourscript.py
```

(Substitute the actual path to python on your system, which you can find with:

```
$ which python
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I should have thought about this.

Answer (score 1):

Check the user context that System Scheduler is running under and ensure the location of Python is in it's PATH.